# In Chrome extension, how to open a group of URLs in the current window?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I can open a group of links in a new window like this:

```
chrome.windows.create({url:links});
```

But when I try tabs:

```
chrome.tabs.create({url:links});
```

How can I do this? Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: Simply do it in the loop. You can add `active:false` for all except the first one to keep it focused.

Comment: sad to hear that loop is the only way :(

Comment: There's nothing sad about that :-)

Comment: If you don't like the loop, try `forEach`, like `links.forEach(url=>chrome.tabs.create({url:url}))`

Comment: Great idea. Thanks!